# Node.JS - Call a Pre-Defined Function in Another Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, nested

I have a function, functionOne, defined normally, outside of other functions or if statements. Now I have another function, functionTwo, and I call functionOne inside of functionTwo. I've tried searching around but I could only find things that told me to define functionOne inside of functionTwo. My issue is that it's already defined, outside of any functions, as I said before.

Here's my code:

```
function functionOne (connection) {
//code here for functionOne
}

function functionTwo (functionOne, connection) {
//some code here for functionTwo

functionOne(connection)
}
```

The error is that the `connection` var isn't being passed over. Any fixes appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: you aren't defining functions correctly. should be: `function <functionName> () {}`

Comment: if you run this code, what error message do you get? :)

Comment: @hackerrdave sorry I messed up in the question, I did actually do that I just forgot to add it there my bad :P

Comment: what do you mean by "connection var isn't being passed over"? how are you invoking functionTwo ?

Comment: @hackerrdave OHHHHH I didn't pass `functionOne` as a parameter when invoking `functionTwo`.... hehe got it fixed now thanks :P

Comment: haha yep no prob

Answer (score 1):

to define a function you should use this syntax:

```
function funcName(args){
    //code
}
```

here in your example you did not define any function. you just called functions that don't exist.

Comment: sorry I messed up in the question, I did actually do that I just forgot to add it there my bad :P

Comment: then you don't need to pass functionOne as an argument to functionTwo

Comment: Thanks but I've already got it figured out in the comments of the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question you just need to provide the argument(s) for the first function within in the second

```
   function funcOne(a){
    return a
}

function funcTwo(b, c){
    //funcTwo's value of "b" will be used for funcOne as the "a" argument
    return funcOne(b) + c
}

console.log(funcTwo(3,4)) //returns 7
```